# Увидят ли мой IP при удалённом доступе?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Захожу на удалённый компьютер со своего. В настройках сети прописал высокоанонимный прокси.

На удалённом компьютере можно посмотреть в логах IP кто юзал комп. Есть шансы что увидят мой настоящий а не прокси?

Comment: Все зависит от того кто и как будет проксировать. Прокси может просто дублировать запросы от своего имени и не выдавать никакой инфы о первоначальном источнике запроса. А может и выдавать :) Также зависит от софта, удаленный сервер может запросить инфу у Вашего клиента, а он может собрать её локально и отправить на сервак.

Comment: @NikolaTesla, http://spys.ru/proxys/UA/ использую те что HIA - высокоанонимные, вероятнее всего они ничего не выдают. И можно ли узнать какую информацию они выдают обо мне?

Comment: т.е. входить через прокси не вариант, тогда как лучше?

Comment: мне таких средств не известно, поднимите свой сервак, снимите дамп трафика и попробуйте разобраться в нем. :) Но это затея так себе.

Comment: почему не вариант? смотря для чего :) В теории запрос можно провести через кучу прокси, но как это сделать на практике мне не известно. И не забывайте, что есть системы типа СОРМ :)

Comment: @NikolaTesla, это только для России?